# How do I call methods from one project in another project?

Tags: c#, class

Hello I have an external class in the class is a method I would like to use how do I get this method to work?
i already added references

This is my class in the extern projekt

```
public class Test {
        static void test1(string value)
         {
            if (values[1] == null)
            {
                // Kein Operator gedrückt
                if (value == "," && values[0] == null)
                {
                    value = "0" + value;
                }
                values[0] = values[0] + value;
            }
            else
            {
                // Operator gedrückt - Zweite Zahl
                if (value == "," && values[2] == null)
                {
                    value = "0" + value;
                }
                values[2] = values[2] + value;
            }
            //Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, values[0] + "|" + values[1] + "|" + values[2], ToastLength.Short).Show();
            
         }
    }
```

and i want to use it here

```
public void ButtonPress(View view) 
    {
        var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.05);
        Button btn = (Button)view;
        if (result_active)
        {
            ClearText();
            result_active = false;
        }
        if ("0123456789,".Contains(btn.Text)) {
            UpdateText(btn.Text);
        }
        else if ("+-*/".Contains(btn.Text)) {
------> Calculator.Test(btn.Text);
        } else if ("=".Contains(btn.Text)) {
------>  Calculate.Test;
            Vibration.Vibrate(duration);
        } else if ("AC".Contains(btn.Text)) {
            ClearText();
        } else if ("DEL".Contains(btn.Text)) {
            DeleteLastChar();
        } else {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Not Implemented ;-(", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            Vibration.Vibrate(duration);
        }
    }
```

the firt Test next to the first arrow is underliend red
what am i doing wrong please help.

Comment: Depending on the structure of your Solution you could reference the one project from the other Project. This should allow you to access your external class.

Comment: missing a using ? What is the error you are getting ? what are the proposition of the light bulb https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Retic i did the reference  already

Comment: @Self Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1955 The non-callable member "Calculator.Test" cannot be used like a method. Calculator.Android C:\Projects\Calculator\Sourcecode\Calculator.Android\MainActivity.cs 79 Active

Comment: @Self Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name "Calculate" does not exist in the current context. Calculator.Android C:\Projects\Calculate\Sourcecode\Calculate.Android\MainActivity.cs 81 Active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test class not a static class

so test1 method change public

no static

```
public class Test 
{
    public void test1(string value)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: i removed th static but i cant use the method i think it is a problem with the second part of the code

Comment: @obind you can new Test class?

 `Test test = new Test(); test.test1("val")`

Comment: how to do you mena this and where i add this?

Comment: @obind In the ButtonPress event

Comment: `public void ButtonPress(View view) 
  {
   Calculator.Test test = new Calculator.Test(); test.test1("val");if ("0123456789,".Contains(btn.Text)) {
    UpdateText(btn.Text);
   }
   else if ("+-*/".Contains(btn.Text)) {
    Calculator.Test()(btn.Text);`

Comment: i added it like that but "Test" is underliend red

Comment: @obind `Calculator.Test()(btn.Text)` change `test.test1(btn.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to your project. Select the project you need and click ok.

[image: add reference]

Comment: after that you'll need to import the namespace into your main class. At the top of your file.

Comment: The namespace is the same